# Template function dependent on non-type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-function

Is it somehow possible to define an overloaded template function based on a non-type parameter?

following situation:

```
template<uint8_t> void SetupMem();

template<> void SetupMem<4>()
{ /* some code */ }


template<> void SetupMem<8>()
{ /* some code */ }

void TemplateCaller()
{
   // use the plattform-specific template function at compile-time
   SetupMem<sizeof(size_t)>();
}
```

now is it somehow possible to change the return value of `SetupMem` based on the non-type parameter?
e.g.:

```
template<> uint32_t SetupMem<4>(){}
template<> uint64_t SetupMem<8>(){}
```

So that `TemplateCaller()` does not explicitly calls `SetupMem` with the desired template parameter (so avoiding something like: `SetupMem<uint64, sizeof(size_t)>();`)? Possible solutions upto C++11 are welcome :)

Comment: Isn't this an XY problem? If you're only worried about `size_t`, then simply use `size_t`. Note that many libraries these days come in 32 and 64 bit versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use simple *function overloading* and `std::integral_constant`:

```
std::uint32_t SetupMem(std::integral_constant<int, 4>); // (0)
std::uint64_t SetupMem(std::integral_constant<int, 8>); // (1)

void TemplateCaller()
{
   auto a = SetupMem(std::integral_constant<int, 4>{}); // calls (0)
   auto b = SetupMem(std::integral_constant<int, 8>{}); // calls (1)
}
```

You can introduce a template type alias for readability:

```
template <int X>
using ic = std::integral_constant<int, X>;

std::uint32_t SetupMem(ic<4>);
std::uint64_t SetupMem(ic<8>);

void TemplateCaller()
{
   auto a = SetupMem(ic<4>{});
   auto b = SetupMem(ic<8>{});
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CFo1E9lduVrOdziP)

---

If your compiler doesn't support `integral_constant`, all you need to do is define it yourself:

```
template <int>
struct ic { };

std::uint32_t SetupMem(ic<4>);
std::uint64_t SetupMem(ic<8>);

void TemplateCaller()
{
   auto a = SetupMem(ic<4>{});
   auto b = SetupMem(ic<8>{});
}
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/J2foOxbPtpussOxF)

Comment: Usage in sense of question would be `SetupMem(ic<sizeof(size_t)>());`

Comment: I like this, cos it's uber-simple and that's never a bad thing.

Comment: I really like this solution, but unfortunately std::integral_constant is not yet offered by our "special" compiler. Therefore, I will just give a simple upvote here.

Comment: @mbed_dev Workaround: define your own integral constant then: `template <size_t> ic {};` should be all you need, as you only need the template type to select the correct overload...

Comment: @Aconcagua could you complete the example?

Comment: @mbed_dev: I think you should follow Aconcagua's suggestion, `integral_constant` is trivial.

Comment: @mbed_dev: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can write a type trait:

```
template<::std::size_t x_Size> class
t_IntegralFromSize;

template<> class
t_IntegralFromSize<4> final
{
    public: using type = ::std::uint32_t;
};

template<> class
t_IntegralFromSize<8> final
{
    public: using type = ::std::uint64_t;
};

template<::std::size_t x_Size> typename t_IntegralFromSize<x_Size>::type
SetupMem();

template<> t_IntegralFromSize<4>::type
SetupMem<4>()
{ /* some code */ }


template<> t_IntegralFromSize<8>::type
SetupMem<8>()
{ /* some code */ }

void TemplateCaller()
{
    // use the plattform-specific template function at compile-time
    SetupMem<sizeof(size_t)>(); // works without changes
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dDxvvFQhWieGMHw1)